# convert XML to JSON or Avro (in python)

Tags: python, json, xml, avro

I am trying to convert XML to JSON or Avro schema in python.

Do you have any suggestions?

I tried already this code:

```
    import xmltodict
    import json

    with open('xmlskuska.xml') as fd:
         doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

    app_json = json.dumps(doc)
    print(app_json)

    with open('skuska.txt', 'w') as json_file:
         json.dump(doc, json_file)
```

The thing is that I want to rename those attributes names during conversion.
This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
    <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2009-12-15</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cac:OrderReference>
        <cbc:ID>123</cbc:ID>
    </cac:OrderReference>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0.75</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

For example, i want to rename attribute cbc:ID to just ID.
Do you have any suggestions how to make this conversion which I want with a nice JSON or better Avro output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type(doc)` is an ordered dictionary. Therefore, you can modify individual keys before converting it to a json file. For example:

```py
import xmltodict
import json

with open('xmlskuska.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

# Get the old value for cbc:ID and assign it to ID
doc['Invoice']['ID'] = doc['Invoice'].pop('cbc:ID')

app_json = json.dumps(doc)
print(app_json)

with open('skuska.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(doc, json_file)
```

Comment: Yes this works, but it adds the new dictonary value to the end of the file. I need to do this action with all attributes if I want to save the structure of the XML. Thank you, you helped me!